# The character 双 in the dish name 炒双冬。

Tags: characters, character-identification

How did the character 双 in the dish name 炒双冬 come to mean "bamboo shoots"? Isn't 双 just a character meaning "pair"? Also, why 冬(winter)?

Comment: http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_3d93e4800100hbfh.html 唯炒双冬，冬笋占了半壁江山，算是半个主角。还有一“冬”是香菇，上海人叫香覃，北方人叫冬菇，这原是一道鲁菜，所以就叫炒双冬。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

双means two，冬is short for冬笋and冬菇。双冬here means冬笋and冬菇。

Answer (score 6):

I think it's 炒双冬. 双 here means two. One 冬 is 冬菇, also known as 香菇, a kind of mushroom, lentinus edodes. The other 冬 refers to 冬笋, bamboo shoots.

Comment: Thanks. My pleco dictionary does not list 双笋。